# A One-Directional Riddle

Tags: riddle

> I am powerful on one side,
>
> twice when I am infinite,
>
> while half of me negates,
>
> my other inflates.
>
> You could call me an A ray,
>
> or maybe a sill ender,
>
> but never, ever shall you
>
> call me a well rounded figure.
>
> I can fly, or I can spin,
>
> but never will I have a double end.

Hint:

> LDRUL

Hint (Probably gives away the answer):

> Magnet

Comment: If there is some reason (beyond "that wasn't what I was thinking of") why the existing answers do not solve this puzzle, it's not apparent at all what part of the puzzle actually invalidates those responses. Because it seems they should be at least as valid as any other answer you might have in mind, this is looking "too broad" and may be put on hold as such. You may need to update the puzzle to make sure invalid responses are demonstrably invalid.

Comment: @Rubio Okay...will do. Just wondering (sorry, I don't ask many riddles), is "that wasn't what I was thinking of" not a valid reason for not accepting an answer to a riddle?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Only if the expected answer is a better fit for the given clues. Otherwise, questions like "What number am I thinking of?" would be valid puzzles.

Comment: @Rubio Oh, okay. But so far, I can find a (small) problem with every answer here

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Then you may want to give answerers more specific feedback than "not correct". I'm having trouble finding a reason why at least two of these answers don't fit the riddle; perhaps an explanation of why you think the answers don't work will nudge someone in the right direction to actually solving it. Also note that even a *correct* answer may not fit the question perfectly because the answerer is not inside your head and doesn't get every detail or nuance. But a question that is *Too Broad* permits multiple "adequate answer"s—plausible fits not ruled out by the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

> Halbach array

I am powerful on one side,

> The Halbach array is constructed to increase the magnetic field on one side.

twice when I am infinite,

> If the array is infinite, it can double the strength on one side.

while half of me negates,

> Part of the array is positioned to negate the magnetic field on one side

my other inflates.

> The other parts inflate the strength of the array on the other side.

You could call me an A ray,

> it is an array

or maybe a sill ender,

> There are halbach cylinders where the field is strong either on the inside or outside, and negated in the opposite place

but never, ever shall you call me a well rounded figure.

> Not sure on this one, maybe because it is one directional and not like a stereotypical horseshoe magnet?

I can fly, or I can spin,

> Can be used in magnetic levitation (fly) or electric motors (spin)

but never will I have a double end.

> Not sure on this one, but it is one directional and no symmetric to any center so the ends are different (not double ended)

Hint 1:

> This is the pattern of the magnetic orientation in the array and **the key reason this is the correct answer**

Hint 2:

> It is an array of Magnets

For more info:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array

Comment: You may want to add an explanation to every line so that the answer is self-contained and one doesn't have to go through a wiki pass to understand the riddle...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've updated to explain more clearly and not rely on a link.

Comment: Good job! And a 50 point bounty!

Answer (score 22):

You are an:

> **ARROW**

Title: One directional riddle

> Arrows point in one direction

I am powerful on one side,

> The pointy head of an arrow is the "business" end

twice when I am infinite,

> A double-headed arrow represents an infinite length

while half of me negates,

> Half an arrow (i.e. the shaft, without the head) is a negative sign

my other inflates.

> The head of an arrow > is a larger-than symbol

You could call me an A ray,

> A ray of light is sometimes represented by an arrow
>  Alternatively, a mathematical array (i.e. vector) is represented by an arrow (thanks [Mike Q](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30304/mike-q)!)

or maybe a sill ender,

> The end of an arrow (i.e. the shaft) is a cylinder (thanks [Mike Q](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30304/mike-q)!)

but never, ever shall you
call me a well rounded figure.

> Arrows are pointy. Ouch!

I can fly, or I can spin,

> Arrows fly when shot from a bow,
>  Arrows spin when in a spinner (e.g. board games)

but never will I have a double end.

Comment: ROT13 Neenlf (irpgbef) ner ercerfragrq ol neebjf. Na neebj'f funsg vf n plyvaqre. Neebjf ner abg qbhoyr-raqrq.

Comment: Many thanks, @MikeQ , I've incorporated those excellent points!

Comment: Excellent! Not correct, but a good guess!

Comment: Why this is not correct @RedwolfPrograms

Comment: @prit.patel - To be fair, when I read [Mike Q's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/65714/33080) I thought that was the right one as well. Right now, I'm waiting to see if someone else puts out the right answer, or if the OP offers a hint to nudge us in the right direction :-)

Comment: I like the answer, but I think the last line excludes it.  The solution "never will ... have a double end", but this answer counts on it having a double end in line 2.

Comment: @Pugmonkey - that's the head in line 2, not the end. If the object in my answer had two ends (therefore no heads) then it is no longer that object.

Comment: Okay, I'll mark this as correct if nobody answers with what I was thinking of within a week

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms - you can add an answer yourself to indicate what you had in mind (if no one gets it), there's no compulsion on you to pick from one of the current answers. That would also give us an understanding of what you were expecting.

Comment: @Phylyp Yes, but this answer is close, and I'm worried my idea may be "too specific" as few people may have heard of it.

Comment: Fair enough,  @RedwolfPrograms

Comment: I would say sorry that you did not get the bounty, but then again 22 upvotes is more reputation anyway

Comment: No worries, @RedwolfPrograms , there's no way I'd have arrived at an esoteric answer like that! :)

Answer (score 5):

Answer in progress

I think you may be a

> [Cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone)

`I am powerful on one side`

> One side of a cone is a flat face, the other is a point. Depending on context, one side is "powerful".

`twice when I am infinite`

> Still figuring this one out. Perhaps how if you orient two cones to touch at their points (to resemble an hourglass), it looks like the [infinity symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_symbol)?

`while half of me negates`

> One end is infinitesimally small

`my other inflates.`

> As you move along the central axis (away from the pointed end), the radius increases

`You could call me an A ray,`

> In [cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) (3D and polar), you can define a cone in terms of a single vector (array)

`or maybe a sill ender,`

> Cylinders are similar to cones. They can both be defined by a height and a (maximum) radius.

`but never, ever shall you call me a well rounded figure.`

> Cones are not circles or spheres.

`I can fly, or I can spin,`

> Referring to a [nose cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nose_cone) (of an aircraft) or a spinning top

`but never will I have a double end.`

> Cones always have two opposite ends: a pointed end and a flat end.

Comment: Sorry, incorrect. But excellent reasoning!

Comment: My my, I really thought this was the answer!

Comment: wow your infinite thing was pretty amazing :O +1

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

You are a:

> 0(zero)

```
I am powerful on one side
```

> Powerful when placed on right side of any number.For ex - 1000 instead of 100

```
twice when I am infinite
```

> Two zeroes juxtaposed makes the symbol of infinite(a lemniscate).

```
while half of me negates
```

> Zero is at center on number line and its left half negates.

```
my other inflates
```

> Zero is at center on number line and its right half goes to infinity inflating numbers.

```
or maybe a sill ender
```

> Cylinder can be circular seen from top or bottom.

```
but never, ever shall you, call me a well rounded figure
```

> Because it can be elliptical too(not always a perfect circle).

```
I can fly, or I can spin
```

> A balloon(is circular shape) can fly and a coin(also circular shape) can be spinned.

```
but never will I have a double end
```

> Because it's a loop.

I can't relate this entity to an A ray.

Comment: Nice interpretation! For negate/ inflate,  maybe it's position on a number line? And sill ender... the end of a cylinder looks like a ...

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but was not confident that it can be considered.
But now i will add it.@Phylyp

Comment: Hmm, not correct.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is

> a vector
> similar to arrow (given previously)
> but more specific, and won't have a double end

Answer (score 0):

[Partial answer]

I think you are

> A battery

I am powerful on one side,

> A battery stores power but must be oriented the correct way around

twice when I am infinite,

> Not sure

while half of me negates,

> One end is negative (-)

my other inflates.

> The other end is positive (+)

You could call me an A ray,

> AA or AAA batteries

or maybe a sill ender,

> AA and AAA batteries are cylinders (sill enders)

but never, ever shall you

call me a well rounded figure.

> Not sure

I can fly, or I can spin,

> Not sure

but never will I have a double end.

> Not sure

Comment: Interesting idea

Comment: Yea, I was trying to find a way to use your magnet clue. Maybe a compass?

Comment: no, but a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Might this be

> A motor

I am powerful on one side,

> A motor runs one way, clockwise or anti. LDRUL seems to suggest anti CW rotation

twice when I am infinite,

> This is one im confused with slightly. Maybe two motors together as a perpetual motion machine?

while half of me negates,

> Half of the poles are negative in a motor

my other inflates.

> While the other half is positive, at any time. leading to its rotation. (magnet reference)

You could call me an A ray,

> an array of magnetic dipoles

or maybe a sill ender,

> cylindrical in shape

but never, ever shall you

call me a well rounded figure.

> the voltage required is Ac,never a fixed round value (guessing this one)

I can fly, or I can spin,

> Motors can make copters fly, or spin things

but never will I have a double end.

> they have only one shaft

It still doesnt feel completely right. Id thought of

> magnetic and electric dipoles

but those didnt fit well either